# Errors changing ubuntu permission files for bluej

Tags: 12.04

I have currently installed bluej, I am currently stuck on being able to add the external libraries to the bluej userlib. I have tried following the commands giving in edx and end up with this error on my terminal. I have tried the sudo chmod -R with no avail.

```
   zsh: no matches found: kirsnik/usr/share/bluej/userlib/*.jar
```

I am running Ubuntu

```
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 
Release: 12.04 
Codename: precise
```

Comment: Can you please add more information? What commands did you run? What is edx? What is your actual problem with BlueJ?